# Como entrar a la Camara mediante un Botón en Kotlin !

Tags: java, android, kotlin, botón

Hola a todos traigo una duda de principiante ando realizando una Aplicacion el problema es de que cuando quiero entrar a la camara mediante un boton, Me saca de la applicacion.  puedo entrar directo sin boton pero necesito poner un Boton de "Camara" cuando lo presione entre directo a la camara espero que me puedan ayudar, tengo los permisos en el manifest y todo.

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.codetr.tanwir.textandlanguageusecamera">
    <!-- android:installLocation="preferExternal" -->
    <!-- <uses-sdk -->
    <!-- android:minSdkVersion="30" -->
    <!-- android:targetSdkVersion="30" /> -->
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/shutter"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".calculatoractivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity" />.  --- Es la camara

    <activity
        android:name=".startactivity"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/pricechecksinfndo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Estoy tratando de entrar mediante: calculator activity

```
 val boton : Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.ok)
 boton.setOnClickListener {
 val  intent  = Intent(this,CaptureActivity::class.java)
 startActivity(intent)

        }
```

Ando resolviendolo.. cabe mencionar que antes el capture activity era Java lo modifique a Kotlin en si puedo entrar pero se ve la camara y luego se cierra cuando modifico el Activity manifest con esto:

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable" />
```

Regrese al archivo de kotlin a java nuevamente y ya funciono!

Comment: Cuál es el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat cuando se cierra tu app?

Comment: Entiendo que tu consulta es como entrar a la cámara sin salir de la aplicación? Si es así, existe un componente llamado "Camera Preview" https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/camera-preview.

Comment: También veo que comentas que usas "Calculator Activity" para entrar a la cámara pero en tu código esta utilizando "Capture Activity"

Comment: @rguzman Gracias por responder amigo estoy utilizando calculator activity para entrar a la camara en si no uso el capture para nada esta limpio el codigo en el capture. en el calculator tiene un boton de next para entrar a la camara pero me saca de la aplicacion.

Comment: @Jorgesys mensaje de LogCat Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.codetr.tanwir.textandlanguageusecamera.CaptureActivity> cannot be instantiated   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

Comment: Las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. Como ves, el logcat y cualquier cosa que pongas en los comentarios es poco usable.